# First Name and Last Name are set to NULL - Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.2

is there a way to get, what class call a Particular Observer?

I have this Observer,

```
public function execute(
\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData();
    $eventName = $observer->getEvent()->getName();
    $name= $customer->getFirstname();
    $lastname = $customer->getLastName();
    $now = date(‘Y-m-d H:i:s’);
    $this->logger->info($now.'CUSTOMER_SAVE_BEFORE____________’);
    $this->logger->info("Event Name: ".$eventName);
    $this->logger->info('Name: ', $name);
    $this->logger->info('Lastname: ', $lastname);
    $this->logger->info($now.’______________________________________________________________’);

}
```

I need to log, What class Call this Observer, I have an issue on a Magento 2.2.4 Project. Sometimes First Name and Last Name of logged customers are set to NULL, I'm going crazy to understand what is causing this issue...

Thanks
Leonardo

Comment: Which event are you using for this observer?can you please add your event.xml's code here? so i can help you.

Comment: Hi @balwantsingh I'm using customer_save_before....

Comment: use my answer code once and try.let me know if still have an issue

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your code with below code**

```
public function execute(
\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
    $customer  = $observer->getCustomer();
    $eventName = $observer->getEvent()->getName();
    $name      = $customer->getFirstname();
    $lastname  = $customer->getLastName();
    $now       = date(‘Y-m-d H:i:s’);
    $this->logger->info($now.'CUSTOMER_SAVE_BEFORE____________’);
    $this->logger->info("Event Name: ".$eventName);
    $this->logger->info('Name: ', $name);
    $this->logger->info('Lastname: ', $lastname);
    $this->logger->info($now.’______________________________________________________________’);

}
```

I hope it will help..!!